# Pass variable to inner function

Tags: javascript, variables, scope

The problem i am having is that that the propertyAddress is being passed to the GMaps.geocode address, but the map.addMarker title: propertyAddress is the same item, the last item in the array. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

How can I pass the propertyAddress to the inner ap.addMarker, or make a global variable?

This JS scope is not making sense to me

```
// Google Geocode gmaps
var propertyAddress = 'Dallas';

function getPropertyGoecode() {

var map = new GMaps({
    div: '#map',
    lat: 32.7833333,
    lng: -96.8
});
);

var data = Apperyio.storage.appraisalsArray.get();
console.log(data);


$.each(data, function(i, item) {


    propertyAddress = item.PropertyAddress + " " + item.PropertyCity + " " + item.PropertyState + " " + item.PropertyZipCode;
    console.log(propertyAddress);


    GMaps.geocode({
        address: propertyAddress,
        callback: function(results, status) {
            if (status == 'OK') {

                var latlng = results[0].geometry.location;

                console.log('latlng ' + latlng);

                map.setCenter(latlng.lat(), latlng.lng());
                map.addMarker({
                    lat: latlng.lat(),
                    lng: latlng.lng(),
                    title: propertyAddress,
                    infoWindow: {
                        content: propertyAddress
                    },
                    click: function(e) {
                        console.log('propertyAddress ', propertyAddress);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });

});
map.fitZoom();


}

getPropertyGoecode();
```

Comment: ---> `var propertyAddress = item....` Declare you variable properly, and that should fix it.

Comment: If you were hoping the global `propertyAddress` would be sufficient, it isn't because the `callback:` functions are invoked long after the `$.each(...` loop has finished, so that's why you get the last value.

Comment: squint, thank you very much for pointing this out, it fixed my problem. Not sure how I missed this as i have tried declaring the variable that way but not with this particular piece of code. I cant tell you how many ways I have tried to geocode an address and include data from the initial data. The callbacks are confusing.